# Regex matching longer result than expected

Tags: regex

I need to find text `ABRA` inside tags `MadCap:Variable`. I tried to use `/variable.*ABRA.*\//g>`, but it matching longer result than I expected.
[Sample of my test](http://regexr.com/3g1rf)

I would expect that I get only something like `variable name="General.ProductNameABRAG1" />` instead of text in example. Where is my mistake?

**edit**. as Wiktor Stribiżew pointed out, for parsing XML or HTML is better to use HTML parser. I can't change technology so I'm stucked with `regex`. On other side, all texts I need to find are guaranteed not to have `>` inside tag.

Comment: @Jan No, see http://regexr.com/3g1ri. Sk1X1, the mistake is that you parse HTML with regex.

Comment: use `[^>]` instead of `.`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew
That's mean is not possible? I'm stucked with using regex for now.

Comment: Why? What is the environment? Regex works on HTML/XML only with assumptions. Like there should be no `>` inside an element node. Then you may use `[^>]*` instead of `.*?`. Or, since `<` should *almost* always be serialized, use `[^<]*` / `[^<]*?`

Comment: It's private application which I got and I can't use others applications because specific usage of this one

Comment: Then you may use `[^<]*?` as a "good-enough" approach. But note that `<` inside a CDATA block still does not have to be `&lt;`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `[^>]` to match any character except `>` which is the end of tag marker insteaf of `.`, also if regex supports lazy/greedy matching `*?` will avoid backtracking.

```
/variable[^>]*?ABRA[^>]*\/>/g
```

Comment: If there is an unserialized `>`  anywhere in between, you won't get a match.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `>` should not appear inside a tag in value it should be escaped `&gt;`

Comment: No, it is not required in some XML parsers. We have to deal with XML that has `>` as is and we could not rely on `[^>]`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for clarification. All files should be safe to use even with this.

Comment: I agree that regex is a lower language, except with extensions as recursive regex in perl